# Equivalent of loglog(MATLAB) to R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a loglog graph but use the non-log labels. So instead of showing in x axis 1 (log10(10), it shows 10. I found the following solution. But that's too much work in my opinion. Is there anything equivalent to the Matlab function "loglog"?

```
plot(log10(x),log10(y),xaxt = "n") 
axis(1,at = c(log10(0.5), log10(10), log10(45),log(100)), labels = c(0.5,10,45,100))
```

Comment: `y = x = 10^(1:5); plot(x, y, log="xy")`

Comment: `?plot.default` has an example

Comment: Another solution is: options(scipen= 99)
plot(x,y, log= 'xy')

Answer (score 0):

Could be done easily with `ggplot`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(tibble)
tibble(
    x = seq(1, 10, .01),
    y = sin(log(x)*pi) + 2
) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_continuous(trans = log_trans()) + 
    scale_y_continuous(trans = log_trans())
```

[image]

```r
# Or for log10 it can be done without trans:
tibble(
    x = seq(1, 10, .01),
    y = sin(log(x)*pi) + 2
) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_log10() + 
    scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I see, thanks for the help!